# Google Prettify line color beyond visible area (pre-scrollable)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pretty-print

I'm looking to extend line highlighting on a pre tag using Google Prettify. This is what I have. I'm looking for a way to extend line highlighting as far as possible.

Thanks.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
  <style>
      pre {
         max-height: 100%;
         /* These aren't needed for Google Chrome, but are needed for Edge to force no-wrap*/
         word-break: normal !important;
         word-wrap: normal !important;
         white-space: pre !important;
     }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre id="code_insert" class="prettyprint linenums lang-java pre-scrollable">
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("If you scroll past the visible area, really really really really really far, the line highlighting is going to break......");
  return;
}
    </pre>
    <script>
      PR.prettyPrint();
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is what the output looks like on Google Chrome 66 & Microsoft Edge 41 (Windows 10).

[image: As you can see the line highlighting stops]

Comment: Your code snippet when run via StackOverflow doesn't seem to exhibit the problem on my browser since it's not possible to scroll farther to the right? Of course, that might just be me.

Comment: I posted the picture of what the output looks like on my end. It's the blue/white line highlight  that's not working.

Comment: Yeah - I can't replicate that in Safari, since the lines wrap around. The screenshot definitely makes it clear what the issue is though.

Comment: I added some extra CSS to force no-wrap.

Comment: From what I can tell after some experimentation, the highlighted lines highlight based on the size of the window/div, regardless of scrolling.
Looking at https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/prettify.css , it's applying { background: #eee } to odd numbered lines.

Comment: I took a deeper look and what Bootstrap is actually doing with the pre-scrollable class is this:
`.pre-scrollable {
  max-height: 340px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}`
Therefore, the problem likely boils down to interaction between `overflow-y: scroll` and pretty-print's handling of line backgrounds.

Comment: Additionally, pretty print is, under the hood, inserting ol and li elements into the pre block. The ol is not filling the entire pre block, hence why its width is limited based on the window/div size.

Comment: Is there a way to trick prettyprint in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172532/discussion-between-andrew-fan-and-boris).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found that the following CSS fixes it:

```
pre {
    display: flex;
}
```

Now I can scroll the code sideways the lines are highlighted properly.

With this the area without code won't expand to the available width, so different code snippets will be shown using varying widths. To fix that you will also need to do this:

```
ol.linenums {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Hope this helps.